# xdotool recorder

Tags: bash, user-interface, automation, xdotool

Does anybody know of an automated xdotool script generator? Ideally, I would like to record a series of actions on my desktop and have it automatically made into an xdotool script for me instead of manually adding pauses and counting pixels, etc.

Answer (score 8):

I can't say for sure without knowing more about what you want to do, but I think you might want to use `xmacro` instead. There is a good tutorial here:
http://linuxpoison.blogspot.in/2012/03/record-play-keystrokes-and-mouse.html

Here's a summary:

```
# Start recording macro.
xmacrorec2 > macro.txt
# Select a keystroke to end the macro.
# Do stuff.
# End the macro with the previously chosen keystroke.
```

And to run the macro:

```
xmacroplay $DISPLAY < macro.txt
```

The blog post notes that timing information is not recorded.

Comment: // , Would you be willing to include a quick paragraph summary of the tutorial? Bullet points?

Comment: Sure, I did it just now.